# LoadLibrary not failing on missing DLL: why?

Tags: c#, interop

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious in the documentation. I'm calling `LoadLibrary` from C# and passing in a DLL that isn't there. I'm getting back `IntPtr.Zero` as I would expect, but when I call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` I always get 0.

Here's the sample.

```
class Program {

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        IntPtr pDll = LoadLibrary(@"c:\NotThere.dll");
        int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        Console.WriteLine(err);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I'm adding code like this to a program that's already failing to load a DLL for no apparent reason. Any idea why I'm not getting an error message?

Comment: what happens if you do `Assembly.LoadFrom(...)`? Unclear if the DLL is unmanaged, which I assumed it is.

Comment: wow... so many people below obviously found the same Google page to answer this... either that or everyone spells `dllToLoad` the same.....

Comment: @JD - Or we simply added the flag to the OPs code above.

Comment: @0A0D, you're right I didn't specify. It's an unmanaged DLL.

Comment: @JD Some of us can answer SO questions without Google's help  ;-)

Comment: @David Heffman: A dying breed... Someone I was interviewing, when asked about how to use generics in C#, once said to me "You don't need to have the knowledge anymore, you just need to know it exists. Google will do the rest." Interesting comment... But they didn't get the job.

Comment: @JD Knowing how to use websearch is an essential skill. But there are still an awful lot of things that one needs to know by heart. For a C# programmer I'd class knowledge of generics as something that needs to be known by heart.

Comment: @David Heffman: Exactly my point.. Especially someone who was a 'mid-level developer'. I was interested by the quote, but (to be honest), if you need to search for information on using Generics... 'nuff said!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For errors to get logged so that they can be read by `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`, you need to have `SetLastError=true` on the `DllImport` attribute:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);
```

Answer (score 9):

Your code doesn't set the [DllImport.SetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror.aspx) attribute flag, which might be why [GetLastWin32Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) isn't returning anything:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);
```

To diagnose why modules aren't being loaded you should check [Fusion logs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (if the module is a managed assembly), and / or [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Bear in mind that the load error might be caused because a dependent module could not be loaded (e.g. the VC9 redistributable, on which all C++ modules compiled with the VS2008 compiler depend on), and so even if the module is architecture compatible and located in a searchable directory (such as the application or system directory), the module may still fail to load - Dependency walker is very good at highlighting these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare in your `DllImport` attribute that you want the last error to be captured using the `SetLastError` field. For example:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following `DllImport`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);
```

Answer (score 2):

try to add this attribute:

```
[DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

from msdn:

> Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function that was called using platform invoke that has the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set.